# istanbul ignore if not working - Server side test

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, istanbul

I want to skip the second if statement
While testing I won't pass any "userid" hence I want to skip the second if.

```
async update(id: string, userid: string, input: UpdateNotificationInput) {
    const items = await this.model.query('id').eq(id).exec();
    if (items.length === 1) {
      /* istanbul ignore if */
      if (items[0].userId !== userid) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
      }
      const { appTargetId, createDate } = items[0];
      return await this.model.update({ appTargetId, createDate }, input);
    } else {
      throw new BadRequestException();
    }
  }
```

The below if shouldn't be accessed.

```
if (items[0].userId !== userid) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
      }
```

My "istanbul ignore if" or "istanbul ignore next" doesn't seem to work. 
When I run my test coverage the if statement is accessed and I get an error.
Am I using it in the correct way?

Comment: For those who just like me wonder what 'istanbul' is: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/ignoring-code-for-coverage.md

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you never pass userId in tests, so the `if (items[0].userId !== userid)` condition is always true, and your test fails.

`/* istanbul ignore if */` comment only disables accounting for this line in the coverage report. It does not prevent your test runner from executing the line.

If you want to ignore the line in tests you should make it conditional on the test environment. In node you could for example use:

```
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV != 'test' && items[0].userId !== userid) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
      }
```

and then run your tests with NODE_ENV=test env variable set (which is the default in most setups).

Better approach would be to actually pass correct userId in your tests. Then the `istanbul ignore if` comment would make the contents of the if statement not counted towards the test coverage, so you do not have to write that additional test for bad request condition.

Personally I'd just write such test though, to be sure I'm actually returning correct error in such situation.